# Describing derived category of coherent sheaves concretely

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

The following question came up when I was asked to do prove equivalence of some derived categories 'by hand'(I find it hard to define this..).

How does one describe $D^b(X)$? It seems one good idea is to use semi-orthogonal decomposition, but this seems hard even in some easy cases. For example, if $X=\mathbb{C}^2$, $Coh(X)=Mod(k[x,y])$, can we say something more about the structure of $D^b(X)$ except 'it is the derived category of $Mod(k[x,y])$.

To take one more step, what can one say about the derived category of G-equivariant coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{C}^2$ when $G$ is the group of order 2 with standard action.

Thanks in advance for any help.